# Django Rest Framework SimpleRouter inclusion inserts ^ into url pattern

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have DRF application with urls defined using `SimpleRouter`.

```
# project/app/urls.py:

from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
from .viewsets import ExampleViewset, TopViewset

router = SimpleRouter()

router.register(r"example/", ExampleViewSet, basename="example")
```

I imported this router to main project urls file.

```
# project/urls.py:

from project.app.urls import router as app_router
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("app/", include(app_router.urls)),
]
```

`GET` localhost:8000/app/example/ returns 404.

Opening localhost:8000/app/example/ in browser returns this error page:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/app/example/

Using the URLconf defined in backend.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
app/ ^example//$ [name='example-list']
app/ ^example//(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='example-detail']

The current path, app/example/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I expected `app/example` in URLconf, but instead there is `app/ ^example`. I think ^ means beginning of line. So my question is, why this happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove trailing slashes from registrations:

```
router.register(r"example", ExampleViewSet, basename="example")
```

Now correct url is generated.